# htaccess file not working correctly after Migrating to new host

Tags: apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I've just migrated web hosting and the .htaccess file isn't functioning correctly on the new host.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&%{QUERY_STRING}&param=%{REQUEST_URI}
```

The front end of the website works perfectly but when I attempt to access the admin area http://www.website.com/Manage the url is getting rewritten even through the Manage directory is available for the web server to read. When I removed the rule the admin area works again.

I attempted to add a rewrite condition to exclude the admin directory but didn't have any luck.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following doesn't only check if the requested url is a existing file, it also checks if it's a folder.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1&param=%{REQUEST_URI} [QSA]
```

PS I also cleaned up your rule a bit.